# How to Setup OptiX in Blender 2.81?

Tags: rendering

I have a laptop with RTX 2060 graphic card and I want to use its ray tracing technology in blender. I saw the blender tutorial and I didn't understand nothing. I have no idea how to use CMake, how to build an environment and how to use git. can someone please send me a complete tutorial (without link to other websites) to how to setup OptiX? Can someone make a step by step guide? Thanks for everyone that help me :)

Comment: One step is to go into preferences and put it on optix.

Comment: I don't have my graphic card in the list. I need to build blender.

Comment: Because you have RTX try CUDA